# Updating two tables sql

Tags: java, sql

I have a table tblPurchase and tblSale i want to update the quantities of both tables as an salesperson purchases some thing from the seller

```
create table tblPurchase(
                         id int primary key,
                         p_name varchar(50) ,
                         p_qty int, 
                         date varchar(50),
                        cust_name varchar(50)
                         )
```

the second table is

```
    create table tblsale (
                  id int primary key,
                  p_name varchar(50),
                  p_qty varchar(50),
)
```

now how can i update tblpurchase on a sale in tblsale?
here is the stored procedure i tried to use but i want to implement in java how to do it?

```
create proc deduce 
            @p_id int @p_quantity varchar(50)
         as
            update tblpurchase set p_qty = p_qty - @p_quantity
            update tblsale set s_qty = s_qty + @p_quantity
            where @p_id = @p_id
```

Comment: you can use a triggers did you try to do something?

Comment: i tried stored procedures.

Comment: you are close, then you have to share what you tried so we can help you

Comment: but the problem is i am unable to implement it in java

Comment: updated the question

Comment: did you try to use this https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Comment: read this also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-stored-procedure.htm

Comment: *"i want to implement in java how to do it?"* Exactly the same way, you execute **two** update statements. Since you want both to succeed or fail together, turn auto-commit off, and commit/rollback the transaction as appropriate. --- *FYI:* Your stored procedure doesn't work, because with a `where` clause, *all* rows are updated in table `tblpurchase`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to answer this entirely, but I can give you a hint. Create triggers which gets triggered when there is some sale in tblSale table. 
Another problem I see is that in tblSale, why is p_qty a varchar? It should be int.